# Convert image to binary to store in database in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I want to store the image(any type of image) into the database by using `varbinary(MAX)`.

My Database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pic]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [picture] VARBINARY(MAX) NULL, 
    [origin] NVARCHAR(100) NULL
)
```

My code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] imagebyte = File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/") + imageUpload1);

    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into Pic values('"+ imagebyte +"','"+ lblOrigin.Text +"')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

when I run my code, I get this error:

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Images *are* binary. The problem is that you're using string concatenation to create queries, something that exposes you to SQL injection attacks, conversion errors and actually makes it impossible to pass dates, numbers or ... images without conversion issues. Use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert PictureBox to Sql Server Database Varbinary(MAX) with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323124/how-to-insert-picturebox-to-sql-server-database-varbinarymax-with-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use parameterized sql queries, to retrieve data, but also to store data. This will prevent SQL injection attacks from happening, and will enable you to store (large) binary objects in your database.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand()) {
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.CommandText = "insert into Pic (picture, origin) values(@image, @origin)";

  // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", imagebyte);
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
  cmd.Parameters["@image"].Value = imagebyte;

  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@origin", lblOrigin.Text);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: AddWithValue is dangerous as string concatenation. In this case it will assume that the actual parameter size equals the length of the values, whether it does or not. This can easily lead to truncation

Answer (score 0):

Here is a resource for you to look at. I think [this](http://www.shabdar.org/sql.../105-store-save-images-in-sql-server.html) will solve your problem.

Just a note: Use stored procedures when doing operations on a database in your code.