# Insert pdf file as varbinary(max) into the database using web API in Angularjs?

Tags: c#, sql-server, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have tried inserting pdf file into the database, but it is getting inserted as 0 for `int` datatype and null for `varbinary(max)` into the database. I have also tested using postman, by passing the data into web API controller, but still it is getting inserted as 0 and null into the database.

```
[HttpPost]
        [ActionName("addReceiptDocument")]
        public int insertReceiptDocument(receiptDocument rd)
        {
            rd = new receiptDocument();            
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
            myConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ERPConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            //DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT_RECEIPT_DOCUMENT";
            sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RDID", rd.RDID);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RECEIPTID", rd.RECEIPTID);
            //var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            //var filePath = "Z:\\Templates\\Images\\" + request.Headers["filename"];
            //using (var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
            //{
            //    request.InputStream.CopyTo(fs);
            //}
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOCUMENT", rd.DOCUMENT);
            myConnection.Open();
            int rowInserted = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
            return 1;
        }
```

```js
$scope.submit = function (files) {
    //var fd = new FormData();
    //Take the first selected file
    //fd.append("payloadFile", 33);
    //fd.append("payloadFile", 98746);
    //fd.append("payloadFile", files);

    $http.post('http://localhost:49556/api/purchaseOrder/addReceiptDocument',
               fd, { headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined } }
    ).then(function (response) {
        alert('success');
    })
}
```

```html
<form name="oForm" id="oForm">
    File: <input type="file" id="payloadFile" name="payloadFile" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"  ng-click="submit(files)" />
</form>
```

```
public class receiptDocument
    {
        public int RDID { set; get; }
        public int RECEIPTID { set; get; }
        public byte[] DOCUMENT { set; get; }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert PictureBox to Sql Server Database Varbinary(MAX) with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323124/how-to-insert-picturebox-to-sql-server-database-varbinarymax-with-c)

Comment: Slightly matching, but I wanted to insert a pdf file

Comment: Just like your other question, you are getting a blank document inserted into your db because you are setting rd = new reciptDocument.  Therefore wiping out whatever data was passed as a parameter to your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@DOCUMENT", rd.DOCUMENT);
```

you can write

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@DOCUMENT", SqlDbType.VarBinary, rd.DOCUMENT.Length).Value = rd.DOCUMENT;
```

also cross check whether you are getting correct value in `rd.DOCUMENT`

Comment: Getting an error, something like this :Error 3 No overload for method 'AddWithValue' takes 3 arguments \api\Controllers\purchaseOrderController.cs

Comment: updated, I guess you are using latest version of .net, docs here
: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameterCollection_Add_System_String_System_Data_SqlDbType_System_Int32_

Comment: Get an nullreference exception